# Is there any way to create a socket in Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, tcp, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have been trying to create a socket in a portable class library. Tried a solution from xamarin forum too, but no luck. Is there any way to create a tcp socket inside a portable class library?

Comment: PCL isn't a single thing. What's available depends on *which* combination of platforms you're targetting.

Comment: Actually I am targeting for the all xamarin platforms including wpf and windows phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: you can't.

TCPI/IP sockets or UDP sockets (i.e.) are just communication protocols in the Internet that uses the **transport layer** and lot of anothers resources of you host machine (More info: [wikipedia/tpc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol))

Comment: Yeah you are correct! we can't. But we can use the interface in the PCL. I guess I found that one in blog.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

[Sockets for PCL](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl) is a .NET library that allows you to use sockets in a cross platform way for Xamarin iOS/Android/Forms, Xamarin.Mac/MonoMac, Windows Phone 8/8.1, Windows Store and Windows Desktop!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create a socket as the Xamarin PCL profile does not contain the namespaces.

But you can easily implement a native provider on the specific platform projects and use the dependency injector to retrieve an interface to them, that's the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess, i found the library that interfaces the native System.Net.Sockets and it is working.

Comment: Hi @ChandanGupta What library would that be?

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas I have used the library available in github. Its here https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Comment: @IgorKondrasovas here is the nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/rda.SocketsForPCL/

Comment: Beware, I tried to use this sometime ago and I had to write my own service as I had a ton of problems with it.

Comment: @Gusman but this package did solve problem but though some of the functions were manually added later.